# Multiple UITableViewCell types when parsed from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController whose `viewDidLoad` calls an API and retrieves a JSON. It assigns this JSON to a `NSDictionary`. This `NSDictionary` is passed to a `DataModel` class's `parseElements() -> [ Int : [DataModel] ]` method. This method loops through all contents of the `NSDictionary` and constructs one `DataModel` object per iteration and stores it in an array of `[DataModel]`s. The outer loop of the iterator picks up all elements in a `UITableView's section` an inner loop picks up all row contents which are `DataModel` objects in an array. I'm adding all these elements to `DataModel`'s singleton instance so that it is accessible from `UITableViewController`

In the `UITableViewController`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in deciding which type of cell needs to be displayed. I'm getting threading error in the `parseElements()` method's line where I'm adding the array of `DataModel` objects which have just been iterated and collected from the `NSDictionary`.

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue. Conceptually am I approaching it correctly?

Comment: so are you trying to display a TableView while the source for it is being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining index of each section, Store the model of each section as an element of the array.

Element position in array will be your section index, so accordingly you can give number of rows for each section.

Example: 
For each object

1.create data model will be array of objects

2.create response model will be array of sections

DataModel 
{
   NSArray *childObjects
}

for entire response

ResponseModel{
  NSArray *sectionObjects
}

Number of sections will be sectionObjects.count

Number of rows will be DataModel[position].childObjects.count

Comment: Thank you this approach helped me win my problem.